# Change letter in array for 3 different letter

Tags: c, arrays, char

I need to change the text in array in a way, that everywhere I have `a` character, I need to change it to`123`.

Example: for the given text: `ayasxka` I should got this: `12123k123` or this `12323k123` text.

I almost got it to work, but instead of `k` between numbers, I got `s`, I mean, this is my result: `12123s123`.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j = 0;
    char t[] = "ayasxka";
    char *r = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(t) + 2));
    memset(r, '\0', (strlen(t) + 1));

    for(i=0; t[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(t[i] == 'a')
        {
            r[i] = '1';
            r[i+1] = '2';
            r[i+2] = '3';
        }
        else
            r[i+2] = t[i];
    }

    printf("%s\n", r);
    free(r);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your algorithm you should use:

```
for(i=0; t[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if(t[i] == 'a')
    {
        j = i;
        r[j++] = '1';
        r[j++] = '2';
        r[j++] = '3';
    }
    else if(j==i)
        r[j++] = t[i];
}
r[j] = '\0';
```

and in your `malloc` you should add +1 character for the `'\0'`, because `strlen()` doesn't count that, so

```
char *r = malloc(3 + strlen(t));
```

instead of

```
char *r = malloc(2 + strlen(t));
```

This will give you `12123k123`

Comment: I think this is what the OP wanted, but it's not just replacing the occurrent of any `"a"` character with `"123"`. Oh, and the `malloc` would still be wrong, because the OP is not allocating space for the terminating `nul` byte which should be appended at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: You are true, I derived the solution rather from the example then from the description.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `strlen(t) + 2` is not enough, consider the worst case i.e. the string is just made of only `a` characters, then it should be

```
char *r = malloc(3 * strlen(t) + 1);
```

and `szieof(char) == 1` is madatory by the way.

And you will need a counter for the position in the `r` string, say `j`

Try this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j = 0;
    char t[] = "ayasxka";
    /* don't call strlen multiple times, store the value if it wont change */
    size_t length = strlen(t);

    /* it doesn't matter how unlikely malloc will fail, check that + */
    char *r = malloc(3 * length + 1); /*                           | */
    if (r == NULL) /* <--------------------------------------------+ */
        return -1;
    for (i = 0 ; t[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        if(t[i] == 'a')
        {
            r[j++] = '1';
            r[j++] = '2';
            r[j++] = '3';
        }
        else
            r[j++] = t[i];
    }
    /* you don't need the memset */
    r[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", r);
    free(r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you - changed the size, but still have the same, wrong result

Comment: Instead of `12123k123` I got  `123y123sxk123` with your code

Comment: because you said, that every ocurrence of an `"a"` should be replaced by `"123"`? Is that right, or did I get it wrong?

Comment: You are right, but I also gave an example: `Example: for the given text: ayasxka I should got this: 12123k123 or this 12323k123 text.` since the way you did it is pretty ok and I understand this well, I cant figure out how to make it like in my example

Comment: Where did you get that example from? that's not possible because sometimes you are substituting the `"a"` with `"12"` and then other times with `"123"`? So there is no pattern, and hence that is not suitable for a program, unless there is a pattern that I can't see.

Comment: I think I just noticed the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;// j = 0;//unused `j`
char t[] = "ayasxka";
char *r = calloc(strlen(t) + 2 + 1, sizeof(char));//change size, +2: for last a, +1: for NUL
//memset(r, '\0', (strlen(t) + 1));//calloc initialize by 0

for(i=0; t[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(t[i] == 'a'){
        r[i]   = '1';
        r[i+1] = '2';
        r[i+2] = '3';
    }
    else if(r[i] == '\0'){//Not yet been set to the value
        r[i] = t[i];
    }
}

printf("%s\n", r);//12123k123
free(r);
```

---

```
char t[] = "ayasxka";
int i, len = strlen(t);
char *r = calloc(len + 2 + 1, sizeof(char));

for(i=len-1; i>=0; --i){
    if(t[i] == 'a'){
        r[i]   = '1';
        r[i+1] = '2';
        r[i+2] = '3';
    }
    else if(r[i] == '\0'){
        r[i] = t[i];
    }
}

printf("%s\n", r);//12323k123
free(r);
```